# C# Beginner winforms ToString

Tags: c#

Hi I'm trying to multiply 2 numbers together in a simple winform application. The method for multiplying is in the class below and then called in the form when you click a button. I have label called answerText and I'm trying to print my answer in that. my line test.multiplynumbers.Tostring is wrong but not sure what to do there?

```
namespace WindowsFormsApp3
{
class Sums
{
    public int multiplynumbers(int num1, int num2)
    {
        return num1 * num2;
    }
}

}
```

and

```
namespace WindowsFormsApp3
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void AnswerButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Sums test = new Sums();

        test.multiplynumbers(5, 2);
        answerText.Text = test.multiplynumbers.ToString;

    }
}
}
```

Comment: The actual error message is *CS0428: Cannot convert method group 'ToString' to non-delegate type 'string'. Did you intend to invoke the method?*. See duplicate for the solution (you need parenthesis).

Comment: `answerText.Text = test.multiplynumbers(5, 2).ToString();`

Comment: That is what the answers say, yes @Guy

Comment: @PatrickHofman I know, just made it one line answer.

Comment: Please don't use comments for answers @Guy

Answer (score 0):

Assign the result to a variable and then use ToString()

```
 int result = test.multiplynumbers(5, 2);
 answerText.Text = result.ToString();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```
int result = test.multiplynumbers(5, 2);
```

then

```
answerText.Text = result.ToString();
```

or

```
answerText.Text = Convert.ToString(result);
```

Answer (score -1):

ToString is a method and therefore needs (). Update your code like this:

```
namespace WindowsFormsApp3
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void AnswerButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Sums test = new Sums();

        int res = test.multiplynumbers(5, 2);
        answerText.Text = res.ToString();

    }
}
}
```

Comment: Why the downvote?

Comment: I don't get it. Sometimes this community is really messed up.

Comment: While I didn't vote, I hardly see the usefulness to answer this kind of questions.

Comment: I downvoted your first answer as it was wrong. Once you edited it i removed my downvote, but maybe others didn't wait to see that.

Comment: I also think my answer is of no use for the rest of us. But is of use for the op. But I would not be disappointed if it was deleted. @Pikoh you're right. My bad